# Not able to open category post

Tags: plugins, categories, themes

my website home page working perfectly fine all links are clickable and opening, but when I open any menu or category page I’m not able to click and open the post. However, If I right-click and open the post in a new tab or window, it is opening perfectly fine. If I open customize preview mode then also all links are working fine.
Does anyone know what is the issue here and how can I fix it?

The page I need help with: https://cominggames.com/category/best-and-worst/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that one of your plugins has js that disabled the links. Please turn off your plugins one by one and then check.

Comment: I deactivated all plugins  but still not working...any other solution you can suggest...

Comment: Now I am seeing links are working fine. Please let me know have you fixed the issue?